# How to exclude our app From recents list in marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Till `API 22(Lollipop)` exclude from recents list is working fine, but from `API 22` and onwards 
same code is not working.

I am using `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in `manifest` file.

Can anyone help to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWGQm.png)

**Logs**

[Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf2D2.jpg)

Comment: Works fine here. Include your code.

Comment: May be its because you are not asking for user permissions in the app at runtime

Comment: I am using   android:excludeFromRecents="true" in manifest file and its not working in Marshmallow till lollipop its working.

Comment: @Johnny Which permission is required at run time ?

Comment: @AvinashMishra how you are existing your app?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Can you share the code which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in manifest.

Comment: This will close my app , which i don't want , i want that my  app should be in background but not visible in Recent list

Comment: but app is  still coming in recent list in Marshmallow device.

Comment: no its not i have tested it.check the manifest file again  `android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in application and ` android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"` in activity.

Comment: Just after running the app , press recent app  list button it will show our app,  i checked manifest and its same as your code. I edited the question check the screenshot.

Comment: can you post your logcat? do you have teamViwer?

Comment: I added log screenshot in Question Please check. and yes i have teamviwer let me know if u can help